# DatabaseLibrary in RobotFramework

Tags: mysql, database, connection, robotframework

I'm using this libary...

https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.2.2/DatabaseLibrary.html

then in the .robot file I have this set-up:

```
TC check database
    # DatabaseLibrary.Connect To Database  dbapiModuleName=None  dbName=SpecimenDatabase  dbUsername=testenvans_admin  dbPassword=wwSpecimen01  dbHost=specimen.domeinwinkel.nl  dbPort=443  dbCharset=None  dbConfigFile=db.cfg
    Connect To Database Using Custom Params    dbapiModuleName=None, db_connect_string=='SpecimenDatabase', user='Specimen_user', password='SpecimenPassword', host='s99.specimenhost.com', port=5432
```

but no matter what I do it keeps saying:  no Module named  None

what *IS* dbapiModuleName actually?

Comment: this helped dbapiModuleName=MySQLdb

Comment: However the next hurdle is   :   TypeError: connect() argument 20 must be str, not None

Comment: Okay that hurdle countered with : dbCharset=utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your MySQL database from a remote connection. My answer is: https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=308

[image]